# Get the data from mysql rows and display them separately by the ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a mysql table `user` which is consisted of `id, name, password and email` columns.

Is there a way to create some sort of query or java code that will print in my message dialog window all of the users names.

```
try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb","root","");          
      String sql = "select * from user;";
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
      if (rs.next()) {
        val1 = rs.getString(2);
        val2 = rs.getString(3);
      }
      value = val1 + " " + val2;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,value);
    }catch(SQLException e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

This only prints the name and the surname of the first user from the table :(

I want to print them all one below another!

If I set rs.getString(5); - it gives me an error: column index out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you avoid JOptionPane for this kind of code. Better to use some Frame (Swing) and display all of the users into a separate window.

The problem with your code is that variable value is lyiong outside of the loop (which must be btw while loop, as spencer said).

```
try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb","root","");   
  String sql = "select * from user;";
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
  while (rs.next()) {
    val = rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3);
    value += val + " ";
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,value);
}catch(SQLException e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

}

Try to avoid this type of code, use ArrayList and save in the array all of the users credentials. Then easily label it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're only fetching the first row from the resultset. It sounds like you want a loop, and process every row from the resultset.

```
  while (rs.next()) {

  }
```

---

**UPDATE**

**Q:** It only gives me now the last user. Probably because it overwrites the val1 and val2 variable. I suppose somehow this should also goes into the loop..

**A:** Yes, it should go inside the loop. But I'd be populating a collection, rather than concatenating a String.

---

As a performance and maintenance note, you can avoid the messiness of the string concatenation in the Java by doing the concatenation in the SQL statement. I wouldn't use  `SELECT *` and rely on the positions of two particular columns in the resultset.

I'd use a SQL statement like this:

```
  SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) AS user_name FROM users
```

If I wasn't populating a collection, and I needed to concatenate a honkous string, I'd use a StringBuffer, e.g.

```
  val = new StringBuffer(4096));
  while (rs.next()) {
     val.append(rs.getString("user_name"));
  }
  value = val.toString;
```

Comment: It only gives me now the last user. Probably because it overwrites the val1 and val2 variable. I suppose somehow this should also goes into the loop...